# Sets known with Hausdorff distance

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, hausdorff-distance

Let A and B be two arbitrary compact sets. Then what property should hold by A and B such that the distance D(A, B) = D(B, A) = h(A, B), where D is the set distance and  h is the Hausdorff distance. What are these sets known as, for which the above property holds?

Comment: What is the distance $d$?

Comment: The distance between two sets.

Comment: So $A$ and $B$ are not arbitrary compact sets but are compact subsets of the same metric space?

Comment: Yes, these are the compact subsets of the same metric space. and I want to know the class of compact subsets holding the similarity property in distance function.